# php multiple image upload with single browse button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

is it possible to upload multiple images with single browse button as in facebook multiple upload functionality on all browsers > IE6, but without using flash.I have integrated [ajax-multiple-file-upload-form-using-jquery](http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/ajax-multiple-file-upload-form-using-jquery/)  but its browse button not working properly.

I need to click so many times to open a file selection window when i am trying to upload images to different albums.

Answer (score 0):

Try [**Fancy Upload**](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/)! It is free and editable too. Hope you like this. If you are looking for multiple file uploading with a single button try this [**link for demo**](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/3-0/showcase/photoqueue/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a jQuery plugin you could try [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). It's really powerful.

Comment: Yes it uses flash but i believe they were implementing (if they didn't do it already) the html5 option for browsers that supports it.